# AudioKit - app performance improves from the second launch

Tags: ios, swift, performance, audiokit

I am struggling with a very weird issue. My app does sheet music score-following through real-time fft analysis. I am using AudioKit's ffttap, with a timer loop of 0.01 seconds. The session is set to measurement, and the buffer to 0.02.

When I launch the app for the first time after install, the performance of the analysis is less than stellar, to say the least. When I force-close the app and relaunch it, suddenly everything works as expected.

This happens with both release and debug builds, launched from Xcode or independently. The issue does seem to be mitigated somewhat when I install the app from TestFlight.

I don't know where to start looking, and my search yielded no results - as did any attempt to profile the app's performance. Any tips will be welcome. Right now I am desperate enough to try and put an alert on the first run, saying "Welcome! Please force-close the app and launch it again if you want it to work."

**EDIT:** When I place the entire timer into the main thread with DispatchQueue.main.async, the problem seems to go away. This is a workaround, though, and I would still like to know if there is anything else I am missing.

Comment: This is very weird. Its a standalone app, not an AUv3 or used with Audiobus right? I'm sure you would have mentioned it if it were. If you're willing to share the code with me, I'd be very curious to take a personal look. Or else, if you want to do a screen share, I would try to see what I can tell from that.

Comment: I've just given you access to the code on Gitlab. The latest branch I am working on is "share". The relevant file is algorithm.swift. If you want to test the app in action, I can also send you a TestFlight invite.

Comment: Ron, am I missing something about Gitlab? I see no code, just a message saying the project has no wiki yet. Perhaps as a guest I can't access the code?

Comment: Seems like something the Gitlab community has been complaining about for a while: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/40624. In any case, you have been upgraded to a reporter.

Comment: I'm having some issues getting the project compiling on my machine, perhaps a screen share would be best.